# Show That All subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are in the form $n\mathbb{Z}$ with $n>1$

Tags: group-theory

Show that all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are in the form $n\mathbb{Z}$ with $n>1$

I found [a proof on the internet](http://math.ucr.edu/~edwardb/Graduate%20Classes/Math%20201A/201A%20Homework.pdf) that seemed reliable.

The corresponding exercice is exercice 3.

In the second part of the proof  we suppose $H < \mathbb{Z}$ and we want to show that $H = n\mathbb{Z}$

at one point they state:

> We clearly have that $n\mathbb{Z} \subset H$ since $n, −n \in H$ and anything in $n\mathbb{Z}$ can be written as a sum of
>   $n's$ or $-n's$

I don't understand why $n\mathbb{Z}$ must be included in $H$. I understand why $n$ and $-n$ must be in $H$ ($n$ is considered the smallest positive element of $H$) but I don't understand why every other element of $n\mathbb{Z}$ must be in $H$.

**At the end of the proof** we have r=h-nq is smaller than n, by the minimality of n, r=0.
**My question** Why is r necessarily in H?

Comment: Well, $0=0\Bbb Z$ is a subgroup.

Comment: We suppose that  n>1

Comment: In fact, I was observing that the statement "all subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ are in the form [under the for] $n\Bbb Z$ with $n>1$" is technically false. Actually, $\Bbb Z$ too cannot be written in that way.

Comment: For example since $n\in H$, it follows that $n+n\in H$. And therefore so is $(n+n)+n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it this way: If $n \in H$, then you can add $n$ any number of times to itself to get $kn \in H$ for any $k \in \Bbb{N}$. Similarly, if $-n \in H$, then you can add $-n$ any number of times to itself to get $-kn \in H$ for any $k \in \Bbb{N}$. Therefore, $n\Bbb{Z} \subset H$.

$$n \in H \implies n+n=2n \in H$$
$$n \in H \wedge 2n \in H \implies 2n+n=3n \in H$$
$$n \in H \wedge 3n \in H \implies 3n+n=4n \in H$$

Following this pattern, we get $kn \in H$ for $k \in \Bbb{N}$. Repeat with $-n$ to get $-kn \in H$ to complete $n\Bbb{Z}$.